# Chart in winform displaying wrong Point

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, charts, mschart

I have the following code.
I have hardcoded the x and y values to test.
And for some reason for the point (0,-0.5) it plots (1,-0.5)
For the life of me I do not know what is going on, because if you try other values then the graph displays correctly.

```
foreach (var grp in q)
            {
                point = new DataPoint();
                 Sum1 = grp.Sum1 > 2 ? 2 : grp.Sum1;
                Sum1 = Sum1 < -2 ? -2 : Sum1;

                Sum2 = grp.Sum2 > 2 ? 2 : grp.Sum2;
                Sum2 = Sum2 < -2 ? -2 : Sum2;

                point.XValue = 0;
                point.YValues = new double[] { -0.5 };

                chart1.Series.Add(grp.Id.ToString());
                chart1.Series[grp.Id.ToString()].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Point;
                chart1.Series[grp.Id.ToString()].Label = grp.Id.ToString();
                chart1.Series[grp.Id.ToString()].Points.Add(point);
                chart1.Series[grp.Id.ToString()].ToolTip = "THEMES = " + Sum1 + "\n PRICES = " + Sum2;
                chart1.Series[grp.Id.ToString()].LabelToolTip = "THEMES = " + Sum1 + "\n PRICES = " + Sum2;
                chart1.Series[grp.Id.ToString()].MarkerSize = 11;

                chart1.Update();

                if (grp.Id.ToString() == "WW" || grp.Id.ToString() == "PB"
                    || grp.Id.ToString() == "AJ" || grp.Id.ToString() == "AK")
                {
                    avgTheme += (float)Sum1;
                    avgPrice += (float)Sum2;
                    count++;
                }
            }
```

[image]

UPDATE:

this line needed to be added, works only with .NET 4.5

```
          chart1.Series["ABC"].CustomProperties = "IsXAxisQuantitative=True";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is really weird! Looks like a very hard to believe bug. I played around but can only confirm that there seems to be no way to set a single `Point` to position 0 in a `Series`.

Here is a **silly** workaround:

```
S1.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Point;

for (int i=0; i < 2; i++)
{
    DataPoint point = new DataPoint();
    point.SetValueXY(i, -0.5);
    if (i > 0) point.Color = Color.Transparent;
    S1.Points.Add(point);
}
```

I wish I knew what this is about - `Chart` is so ill-documented there might still be some system to the madness..

Update: When you add a `Timer` and let its `Tick` remove the transparent 2nd `Point`, you can see how the 1st `Point` jumps from 0 to 1. So weird..

Comment: Crazy stuff man... this works... I just put a hidden dot at 1,1.

Answer (score 0):

Ah ha....

This is not a bug.  This is the correct behavior for a SERIESCHARTTYPE.POINT of chart.

The purpose of the chart is to show a [b]series [/b]of values {from left to right}, not a set of X,Y points.

Series value 1 is 4
Series value 2 is 1
Series value 3 is 6
and so on.

So the bug is not in the chart, but in understanding what the chart type is designed for and meant to be used for.

You can see here how each element in the array only uses the y value for the point.

[image: Not broke]

Could it be that you want to graph some points?  Maybe you are confusing a *chart* with a *graph*? 
If you are trying to graph points this might help:
https://www.daniweb.com/software-development/csharp/code/217204/function-plotting-in-c

Comment: I don't understand. Have you really read the question? Try this: `S1.ChartType = SeriesChartType.FastLine;
            S1.Points.AddXY(1,  0);
            S1.Points.AddXY(1,  5);` and the try this: `S1.ChartType = SeriesChartType.FastLine;
            S1.Points.AddXY(0,  0);
            S1.Points.AddXY(0,  5);` and now explain!