# Chart: Vertical line and string on X label

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, charts, linechart

I am using WinForms to create a line chart. I have two related questions:

1. How can I draw a vertical line on the chart?

   I have tried to draw a vertical line between two points at (0,0) and (0,5) using:

   ```
   chart1.Series["Pakistan"].Points.AddXY(0, 0);
   chart1.Series["Pakistan"].Points.AddXY(0, 5);
   ```

   However, I get an askew line from (0,0) to (1,5).
2. How can I label this line with a string on the X axis?

Comment: .NET has no built-in chart control. So either you've written your own, or you are using a third-party control. In either case, you need to provide a _lot_ more detail in your question if you want an answer. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sorry for my questions, but i thought that was clear...
I want to paint a line chart with vertical line from for example point (0,0) to point (0,5) using WinForms.
But when I want draw a line, on the chart there is a line from (1,0) to (2, 5), not from (0,0) to (0,5).
So I can't do this using chart from WinForms Toolbox?

Comment: @PeterDuniho, there is a [.Net Chart Control by Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14422). It could be that the OP's machine already had it installed so they didn't know it was a separate package.

Comment: @PeterDuniho The chart control is included in .Net 4.0 and newer.

Comment: Hm, you can easily do it if you pick any other coordinate than x=0. A bug imo; see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26867376/chart-in-winform-displaying-wrong-point/26869668#26869668) although there is a new post there that seems to differ, but I can't understand it..

Comment: @mmathis: ah, I see. The [System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting(v=vs.110).aspx). I made the mistake of taking Microsoft at their word when pre-.NET 4.0 they said Winforms was in bug-fix only mode, no new features. I'd call that a new feature. :) Thanks for the correction. I still say the question needs a lot more detail.

Comment: Did you resolve your problem?

Comment: Yes, but in other way than using a line (or other chart).
I am drawing a vertical line like in the answers below.

Cheers and thanks for answers!

Answer (score 5):

You can use a `StripLine` to show a vertical line on the x-axis:

```
StripLine stripLine = new StripLine();
stripLine.Interval = 0; // only show 1 line
stripLine.Offset = 0; // start it at x=0
stripLine.StripWidth = 1; // the width is 1
// set colors, etc
chart1.ChartAreas["Default"].AxisX.StripLines.Add(stripLine);
```

You could also create a second series of type `RangeColumn`, which takes in 2 y values at each x value, to create the vertical line:

```
Series lineSeries = chart1.Series.Add("line");
lineSeries.ChartType = RangeColumn;
lineSeries.Points.AddXY(0, new []{0, 1});
// Set line widths, colors, etc
```

Finally, you could handle the `PostPaint` event of the `Chart` to draw a line using the `Graphics object:

```
private void chart1_PostPaint(object sender, ChartPaintEventArgs e)
{
  if(sender is ChartArea)
  {

    ChartArea area = (ChartArea)sender;
    if(area.Name == "Default")
    {
        // Get Graphics object from chart
        Graphics graph = e.ChartGraphics.Graphics;

        // Convert X and Y values to screen position
        float pixelYMax = (float)e.ChartGraphics.GetPositionFromAxis("Default",AxisName.Y,1);
        float pixelXMax = (float)e.ChartGraphics.GetPositionFromAxis("Default",AxisName.X,0);
        float pixelYMin = (float)e.ChartGraphics.GetPositionFromAxis("Default",AxisName.Y,0);
        float pixelXMin = (float)e.ChartGraphics.GetPositionFromAxis("Default",AxisName.X,0);

        PointF point1 = PointF.Empty;
        PointF point2 = PointF.Empty;

        // Set Maximum and minimum points
        point1.X = pixelXMax;
        point1.Y = pixelYMax;
        point2.X = pixelXMin;
        point2.Y = pixelYMin;

        // Convert relative coordinates to absolute coordinates.
        point1 = e.ChartGraphics.GetAbsolutePoint(point1);
        point2 = e.ChartGraphics.GetAbsolutePoint(point2);

        // Draw connection line
        graph.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Yellow,3), point1,point2);
    }
  }
}
```

Handling the `PostPaint` is probably the best option, and will give you the best control over your line and its appearance.

Comment: Or maybe a LineAnnotation..?

Answer (score 3):

Q1. : In my opinion you hit upon a bug in the `Chart` control. Here is a **workaround**:

Chose ChartType 'Line' and a nice line width:

```
 chart1.Series["Pakistan"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
 chart1.Series["Pakistan"].BorderWidth = 2;
```

Insert this **dummy** point before the real data:

```
chart1.Series["Pakistan"].Points.AddXY(-1, 0);
```

Now hide the Line segment before the 1st real point:

```
chart1.Series["Pakistan"].Points[1].Color = Color.Transparent;
```

You may want to set the display window to exclude the dummy..

```
Axis XA = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX;
XA.Minimum = -1;
XA.Maximum = yourMaximum;
```

(Until sombody explains it I consider this behaviour it a bug, that only occurs at position X=0..)

Q2. : To add strings as Labels to your data points use code like this.

```
chart1.Series["Pakistan"].Points[1].AxisLabel = "Label 1";
```

[image]