# How to create a line from (0,0) to (0,n) in WinForms chart?

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, point

I tried to draw a line from (0,0) to (0,3) using Winforms chart, but it is drawing a line from (1,0) to (2,3). The same thing happens with any other Y value of the second point.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Series series = new Series("series")
    {
        ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line,
        Color = Color.Red
    };
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        series.Points.AddXY(0, 0);
        series.Points.AddXY(0, 3);
        chart1.Series.Add(series);
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = -2;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = 5;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = -2;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = 5;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Interval = 1;

    }
}
```

[image: chart snapshot]

When I was trying to create a line from (0,0) to (2,3) everything was okay.

[image: chart snapshot]

**How to fix it and what's the cause?**

Comment: [This may be related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26867376/chart-in-winform-displaying-wrong-point/26869668#26869668) - Imo it is a bug. Workaound: Add a dummy first: `series.Points.AddXY(0.0002, 0);`. You may want to make it transparent..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I can tell, when all `X` values are `0`, the chart does not respect value of `0` and thus starts treating your series as though you indented the index of the data point to be your `X` value.

adding a second series with at least 1 data point that has a non-0 `X`, will correct the problem.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Series series = new Series("series")
    {
        ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line,
        Color = Color.Red
    };
    private Series correction = new Series("correction")
    {
        ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line,
        Color = Color.Transparent,
        IsVisibleInLegend = false,
        IsValueShownAsLabel = false,
    };
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        series.Points.AddXY(0, 0);
        series.Points.AddXY(0, 3);

        chart1.Series.Add(series);

        correction.Points.AddXY(1, 1);
        chart1.Series.Add(correction);

    }
}
```